# Why is GLOB extremely slow in ruby-sqlite3 only on Windows?

Tags: sql, ruby, sqlite, sqlite3-ruby

Here's my query (it's automatically generated):

```
SELECT
sn.name,
sa.house_number,
sa.entrance,
pc.postal_code,
ci.name,
mu.name,
co.name,
sa.latitude,
sa.longitude
FROM
street_addresses AS sa INDEXED BY sa_unique_address
INNER JOIN street_names   AS sn ON sa.street_name  = sn.id
INNER JOIN postal_codes   AS pc ON sa.postal_code  = pc.id
INNER JOIN cities         AS ci ON sa.city         = ci.id
INNER JOIN municipalities AS mu ON sa.municipality = mu.id
INNER JOIN counties       AS co ON mu.county       = co.id
WHERE
sn.name GLOB "THORLEIF HAUGS VEI" AND
sa.house_number = 23
ORDER BY pc.postal_code ASC, sn.name ASC, sa.house_number ASC, sa.entrance ASC
LIMIT 0, 100;
```

The `GLOB` is there because this is for a search function that must support wildcards. This query runs perfectly fast on Linux, both in the sqlite3 command line tool as well as in [ruby-sqlite3](https://github.com/sparklemotion/sqlite3-ruby). When on Windows, it runs super fast in the sqlite3 command line tool, but it takes several seconds to execute in Ruby. If I replace the `GLOB` with `=`, the issue disappears.

This is how I tested the query on Windows:

```
> db = SQLite3::Database.open("norway.db")
> sql = File.load("test.sql")
> db.execute(sql)   # SLOW!!!
> db.execute(sql.sub("GLOB", "="))   # Super mega fast!
```

I've run `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` both in the command line tool and through Ruby, both of which indicate that the indexes are being used:

```
selectid    order       from        detail
----------  ----------  ----------  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0           0           1           SEARCH TABLE street_names AS sn USING COVERING INDEX sn_name (name>? AND name<?)
0           1           0           SEARCH TABLE street_addresses AS sa USING INDEX sa_unique_address (street_name=?
0           2           3           SEARCH TABLE cities AS ci USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?)
0           3           2           SEARCH TABLE postal_codes AS pc USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?)
0           4           4           SEARCH TABLE municipalities AS mu USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?)
0           5           5           SEARCH TABLE counties AS co USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?)
0           0           0           USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY
```

This is the database I'm using: [norway.db](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vxkvxbliaziedce/norway.db). The link will certainly be broken at some point, but hopefully we've reached a solution by then.

I've done some profiling:

```
result = RubyProf.profile {
  data = db.execute(sql)
}
```

Here are the results:

[image: Profiling results]

Here's the [call graph in text format](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=b6idTwVT).

These lines are of particular interest:

```
  %total   %self      total       self       wait      child            calls    Name
                      2.395      2.395      0.000      0.000              2/2      Kernel#loop
 100.00% 100.00%      2.395      2.395      0.000      0.000                2      SQLite3::Statement#step (ruby_runtime:0}  ruby_runtime:0
                      0.000      0.000      0.000      0.000              2/2      SQLite3::Database#encoding
```

The profiler points me to [statement.rb:108](https://github.com/sparklemotion/sqlite3-ruby/blob/master/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb#L108), which points me to the C function `step`, which is defined in [statement.c:107](https://github.com/sparklemotion/sqlite3-ruby/blob/master/ext/sqlite3/statement.c#L107).

So is this a Windows specific problem in the C code? Is it a SQLite 3 bug or a bug in the ruby library? Any ideas on what I can do to resolve this issue?

---

**EDIT**: Odd, reducing the query to this makes the issue disappear, even though the `GLOB` is still there:

```
SELECT
sn.name,
sa.house_number
FROM
street_addresses AS sa INDEXED BY sa_unique_address
INNER JOIN street_names   AS sn ON sa.street_name  = sn.id
WHERE
sn.name GLOB "THORLEIF HAUGS VEI" AND
sa.house_number = 23
ORDER BY sn.name ASC, sa.house_number ASC, sa.entrance ASC
LIMIT 0, 100;
```

`EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` output:

```
selectid    order       from        detail
----------  ----------  ----------  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0           0           1           SEARCH TABLE street_names AS sn USING COVERING INDEX sn_name (name>? AND name<?)
0           1           0           SEARCH TABLE street_addresses AS sa USING COVERING INDEX sa_unique_address (street_name=? AND house_number=?)
```

Though I'm not sure that matters. As I said, the speed issue seems to be in sqlite3-ruby, not sqlite3 itself.

---

**EDIT:** Odder still, removing sorting from the query also solves the speed problem! This query is fast as lightning on Windows sqlite3-ruby:

```
SELECT
sn.name,
sa.house_number,
sa.entrance,
pc.postal_code,
ci.name,
mu.name,
co.name,
sa.latitude,
sa.longitude
FROM
street_addresses AS sa INDEXED BY sa_unique_address
INNER JOIN street_names   AS sn ON sa.street_name  = sn.id
INNER JOIN postal_codes   AS pc ON sa.postal_code  = pc.id
INNER JOIN cities         AS ci ON sa.city         = ci.id
INNER JOIN municipalities AS mu ON sa.municipality = mu.id
INNER JOIN counties       AS co ON mu.county       = co.id
WHERE
sn.name GLOB "THORLEIF HAUGS VEI" AND
sa.house_number = 23
LIMIT 0, 100;
```

What the heck is going on here!? Here's the `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` output:

```
selectid    order       from        detail
----------  ----------  ----------  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0           0           1           SEARCH TABLE street_names AS sn USING COVERING INDEX sn_name (name>? AND name<?)
0           1           0           SEARCH TABLE street_addresses AS sa USING INDEX sa_unique_address (street_name=?
0           2           2           SEARCH TABLE postal_codes AS pc USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?)
0           3           3           SEARCH TABLE cities AS ci USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?)
0           4           4           SEARCH TABLE municipalities AS mu USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?)
0           5           5           SEARCH TABLE counties AS co USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?)
```

Comment: What are the differences in the EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN output?

Comment: What are the differences in the EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN output *for the same query* when fast and slow?

Comment: @CL.: The output is exactly the same; it's the first EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN output of the question. It is fast when run through the SQLite3 CLI and slow when run through sqlite3-ruby.

Comment: What SQLite version are the shell and Ruby using? (execute `SELECT sqlite_version();`)

Comment: @CL.: SQLite3 CLI version is 3.8.5 and the version inside the ruby gem is 3.7.17 (found using `SQLite3::SQLITE_VERSION`)